# (new) Macbookair freezing for minutes, roughly 5 times per day, mouse movable - what could be the source of the issue?

Tags: mac, freeze, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-air, console.app

Below the output of the console. I made the start and endpoint of the freeze bold. Do you have any idea what could be the source?

```
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: [EWOULDBLOCK][vnode:0xffffff801d9fbd90][original:0xffffff801d9fbd90][callback: 0 count:267 ] onaccessctl_check:1717 result:0 disconnected:0    
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: current scan list:   
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: (pid 17159 [mtmd], vnode 0xffffff801d9fbd90 [/Users/theair/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Session Storage/000263.log], [context 0xffffff801983c690] [result 0] [setup 0] [disconnected 0] [vfsbusy 0]) - 1 waiter(s)    
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: available kctl entries: 9    
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: onaccess_send: NULL target or context; request:0 kctl_entry:0xffffff801c79d000    
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: onaccess_send: not SAV_KCTL_REQ_COMPLETE, return ENOMEM    
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: onaccess_send: NULL target or context; request:3 kctl_entry:0xffffff801c79d000    
06.09.13 19:30:49,000 kernel[0]: sav: onaccess_send: SAV_KCTL_REQ_COMPLETE, intercheck_done()    
**06.09.13 19:30:50,334 coreservicesd[31]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationBirth to notificationID=116**    
06.09.13 19:30:50,334 coreservicesd[31]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationBirth to notificationID=143    
06.09.13 19:30:50,334 coreservicesd[31]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationBirth to notificationID=1346    
06.09.13 19:30:50,362 com.apple.mtmd[17159]: stat on /Users/theair/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History Index 2013-09-journal: No such file or directory   
06.09.13 19:30:50,000 kernel[0]: nspace-handler-unblock: did not find token 301236    
06.09.13 19:30:50,912 WindowServer[82]: reenable_update_for_connection: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Microsoft Outlook" after 596.34 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)    
06.09.13 19:30:51,481 coreservicesd[31]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=100    
06.09.13 19:30:51,523 coreservicesd[31]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=100    
06.09.13 19:30:51,548 coreservicesd[31]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationReady to notificationID=9717
06.09.13 19:30:54,347 mdworker[80656]: ENSpotlightImporter:managedObjectModel unable to load model at URL file://localhost/.MobileBackups/Computer/2013-09-06-192050/Volume/Users/theair/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/.support/model.mom
```

> **06.09.13 19:30:54,348 mdworker[80656]: ENSpotlightImporter:importFileAtPath:attributes:error: caught exception: Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model**

```
06.09.13 19:32:27,316 coreaudiod[172]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active    
06.09.13 19:32:27,491 coreaudiod[172]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive    
06.09.13 19:33:12,332 Dock[183]: no information back from LS about running process
```

Comment: Updated your formatting to be pre-formatted text.  However, I didn't see bold before, so you may want to double check it is as you expect.  Are you doing anything in particular right before this happens?  What version of OSX are you on?  Was it ever *not doing this*?

Comment: 10.8.4. newest generation macbook air. started doing this bascially one week after clean installation at applestore. Thanks for reformatting.

Comment: 10.8.4 is known for freezing a lot, however, do you have any 3rd party software running or devices connected when this occurs?

Comment: i run sophos (anti virus), dropbox, little snitch, ms office, evernote, chrome. but it also appeared when dropbox, office or evernote were not running...

Comment: You could try running a P-RAM reset, if you do not know what this is at start up hold Cmd+Alt+P+R and wait for 4 charms, however i have seen many cases of this since 10.8.4 was released and most fixes we issue have done nothing, it seems that 10.8.4 is causing more issues than it fixed

Comment: A thread [suggesting Sophos is to blame](http://openforum.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Anti-Virus-for-Mac-Home/Sophos-9-causes-Mavericks-to-freeze/td-p/14893/page/4) rings true for me.

Comment: A thread [suggesting Sophos is to blame](http://openforum.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Anti-Virus-for-Mac-Home/Sophos-9-causes-Mavericks-to-freeze/td-p/14893/page/4) rings true for me.  Common elements include the `nspace-handler-set-snapshot-time` and `nspace-handler-unblock` pair, separated by about 10 minutes of the machine being unable to do IO

Answer (score 0):

As per [@cluesque comment](https://superuser.com/questions/641978/new-macbookair-freezing-for-minutes-roughly-5-times-per-day-mouse-movable#comment1062171_641978), here is [the thread suggesting Sophos is to blame](http://openforum.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Anti-Virus-for-Mac-Home/Sophos-9-causes-Mavericks-to-freeze/td-p/14893/page/4). Common elements include the `nspace-handler-set-snapshot-time` and `nspace-handler-unblock` pair, separated by about 10 minutes of the machine being unable to do IO.

<sup>Related: [Constant beachball and freezes without high CPU usage, “nspace-handler-update: did not find token” message](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/257857/22781)</sup>.